# Reading SNMP V2 OID from ESP8266/ESP32

Tags: esp8266, library, esp32

i need to read from my ESP32/ESP8266 some SNMP V2 OID values from my home printer: it exists a library/method that can do that?

I've seen some SNMP agents, but they works only with the devie as server and not as SNMP client.

Any thoughts?

Comment: SNMP agents *are* servers. In the SNMP world, clients are called managers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you found it, but there I created an SNMP Manager: https://github.com/shortbloke/Arduino_SNMP_Manager

There is also an SNMP Agent: https://github.com/0neblock/Arduino_SNMP

I know this is a bit later than when you requested this info. But posting here in case it's still helpful to you or others that stumble over this question.